# Why do letters keep skipping my "jump if zero" command?

Tags: human-resource-machine

I'm on Zero Preservation Initiative (Lv. 9) and can't seem to get past this area. For some reason letter blocks get past my "jump if zero command" and go to the outbox causing a failure.

Video showing it:

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the letters that are causing it. It's the "Inbox" on line 4.

After getting a non-zero number, the program continues to line 3 and stores it (no idea why- this isn't helping). It then takes an input on line 4, then outputs it on line 5 regardless of what it is.

The program breaks whenever it gets two non-zeroes in a row. Even if you got lucky and got an input that never had two non-zeroes, it would still fail (solutions need to be valid for any input sequence).

I don't want to give away the solution, but the program can and probably should have only one input.

Comment: GAH. Closer but my boss is complaining that it only works under certain inputs. Here is my current flow: https://i.imgur.com/WJ0gv2V.jpg. It worked the first time but he pointed out that I just got lucky with my inputs.

Comment: @Sie Once you get it you'll be kicking yourself. It's an important puzzle though- the solution helps with a lot of others since you're making a "jump if not zero" command.

Comment: Ok I give in. I need one more hint lol. I debugged it and from what I see it should copyto 0 and then go back to the inbox.

Comment: @Sie Make a jump if not zero command out of other things. That's the best I can do without outright solving it.

Comment: I gave in and looked up a guide for it but ya it's stupidly easy as you said... Well at least I know now lol.